# Google bookmarks script only saves about 1 in 5 links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

I've been having this problem with the Google bookmarks "bookmarklet" button in Chrome for several years now: it does not reliably save URLs to https://www.google.com/bookmarks so I have to double-check every link I save. The form is invoked by clicking the Google Bookmark button in the Chrome bookmarks bar that is a javascript link that opens the form. The button comes from the bottom of the Google bookmarks page itself:

[Google Bookmarks page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeVav.png)

[Google Bookmark button properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnI6H.png)

Many links will not save unless I add a suffix such as #1 to the end of the URL, and even that is not a 100% effective workaround. For example, the URL http://jsbeautifier.org/ only saves if I append the #1 in the URL field: http://jsbeautifier.org/#1.

[Google Bookmarks Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDZNa.png)

I don't know if it's an issue with the javascript, encoding the URL, or an issue on Google's end they have never fixed. Here is the full javascript that comes directly from the button properties. I added the whitespace for readability:

```
javascript: (function() {
var a = window,
    b = document,
    c = encodeURIComponent,
    d = a.open("https://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&output=popup&bkmk=" + c(b.location) + "&title=" + c(b.title), "bkmk_popup", "left=" + ((a.screenX || a.screenLeft) + 10) + ",top=" + ((a.screenY || a.screenTop) + 10) + ",height=510px,width=550px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1");
a.setTimeout(function() {
    d.focus()
}, 300)})();
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can anyone confirm if you are having the same issue?  Any thoughts on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue of not able to add a lot of https website into Google Bookmarks, especially those from Github or Google's Chrome Webstore.  Sometimes if you change the https prefix to http, it will work, but not for all.

I guess the problem lies at the backend side, because it also fails when you try to add the URL in question directly at the [Add bookmark](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=add&hl=en) page.

Seems Google deserted this product (originated from the time of Google Toolbar) and favors Google Chrome bookmark sync solution.